# How to get posts by userID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, posts

I am working on a project which demands to show posts of a particular user when a guest or a logged in user clicks on their name, which passes the user's id (whose posts anybody wants to see) to the URL parameters. I have tried to get the user_id from the URL and pass it to the functions which returns all the posts posted by the user.

I am using the MERN stack, and I am sorry for asking such a silly question but, I am new to this technology.

Here is the route for getting the posts:

```
// @route   GET api/posts/posted/:id
// @desc    Get posts by ID
// @access  Public
router.get("posted/:user", (req, res) => {
  Post.find({ user: req.users._id })
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(posts => res.json(posts))
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(404).json({ nopostfound: "No post found with that ID" })
    );
});
```

Here is the action, which is called when the URL is accessed:

```
// Get Posts by userId
export const getUserPosts = user => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setPostLoading());
  axios
    .get(`/api/posts/posted/${user}`)
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_POSTS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_POSTS,
        payload: null
      })
    );
};
```

This is the code sample for showing the posts

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PostedFeed from "./PostedFeed";
import Spinner from "../common/Spinner";
import { getUserPosts } from "../../actions/postActions";

class MyPosts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserPosts(this.props.match.params);
  }
  render() {
    const { posts, loading } = this.props.post;

    let postedContent;

    if (posts === null || loading) {
      postedContent = <Spinner />;
    } else {
      postedContent = <PostedFeed posts={posts} />;
    }
    return (
      <div className="marginContainer">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">{postedContent}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MyPosts.propTypes = {
  getUserPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getUserPosts }
)(MyPosts);
```

This is the PostedFeed code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import PostedItem from "./PostedItem";

class PostedFeed extends Component {
  render() {
    const { posts } = this.props;

    return posts.map(post => <PostedItem key={post._id} post={post} />);
  }
}

PostedFeed.propTypes = {
  posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default PostedFeed;
```

And here is the post's skeleton, which is passed to the MyPost through PostedFeed:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import classnames from "classnames";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import { addLike, removeLike } from "../../actions/postActions";

class PostedItem extends Component {
  onLikeClick(id) {
    this.props.addLike(id);
  }

  onUnlikeClick(id) {
    this.props.removeLike(id);
  }

  findUserLike(likes) {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    if (likes.filter(like => like.user === auth.user.id).length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { post, showActions } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="card mb-3">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-3 text-center m-auto px-0 py-3">
            <img src={post.avatar} alt={post.designation} />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-9 m-auto p-0">
            <div className="card-body m-2">
              <h2 className="card-title">
                {post.designation} - {post.location}
              </h2>
              <div className="mx-2">
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                  <li>
                    <b>Date Posted:&nbsp;</b>
                    <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY">{post.created}</Moment>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <b>Salary:&nbsp;</b>₹{post.salary / 100000}&nbsp;lacs/annum
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <b>Experience Required:&nbsp;</b>
                    {post.experience} years
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <p className="card-text">{post.description}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card-footer mx-3 p-2">
              <div className="row px-3">
                {showActions ? (
                  <span>
                    <button
                      onClick={this.onLikeClick.bind(this, post._id)}
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-light mr-1"
                    >
                      <i
                        className={classnames("fas fa-thumbs-up", {
                          "text-info": this.findUserLike(post.likes)
                        })}
                      />
                      <span className="badge badge-light">
                        {post.likes.length}
                      </span>
                    </button>
                    <button
                      onClick={this.onUnlikeClick.bind(this, post._id)}
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-light mr-1"
                    >
                      <i className="text-secondary fas fa-thumbs-down" />
                    </button>
                  </span>
                ) : null}
                <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} className="btn btn-info ml-auto">
                  View Details
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PostedItem.defaultProps = {
  showActions: true
};

PostedItem.propTypes = {
  addLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  removeLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { addLike, removeLike }
)(PostedItem);
```

Now tell me what should I do in order to populate posts to the page?

Comment: I see only one problem: `Post.find({ user: req.params.user })...`

Comment: getting spinner, which means the posts array is null, not getting the result.

Answer (score 0):

**BACKEND:**

1) `poster/:user` means that **user id** is in `req.params.user`

2) **when** there is **no post** **for user** it will **return empty array**: `[]` so You've to **check empty-ness on client-side**

3) in mongoose error happens if something went wrong - empty result does not throw error

Fix this one and try:

```
// @route   GET api/posts/posted/:id
// @desc    Get posts by ID
// @access  Public
router.get("posted/:user", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find({user: req.users._id}).sort({date: -1}).lean();
    res.status(200).send(posts);
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({error: error.message});
  }
});
```

**FRONTEND**

1) I **cannot see where** You're passing **user id** to function, are You sure that `this.props.match.params` holds **user id**? Could it be: `this.props.match.params.userId` ?

I'm talking about this code block:

```
class MyPosts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserPosts(this.props.match.params.userId);
  }
  ...
}
```

So check Your router and find attribute name.

2) Fix render method to tell that **user has no post**, cause `posts === null` is **not correct** since we **changed backend to return empty array**:

```
render() {
    const { posts, loading } = this.props.post;

    let postedContent;

    if (loading) {
      postedContent = <Spinner />;
    } 
    else 
    if (!(posts && posts.length > 0)) {
      return (
        <div className="marginContainer">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-12">User has no post</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    postedContent = <PostedFeed posts={posts} />;
    return (
      <div className="marginContainer">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">{postedContent}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: this is where the user id is passed from

    <Link className="dropdown-item" to={`/posted/${user.id}`}>My Jobs</Link>

Comment: @RaviGohel I don't see that link in Your question. So please add file to Your question where You've defined that link. Also I've already answered how to fix issue. So the way You're passing that user id to MyPost component up on to You.

Comment: @RaviGohel also add Your frontend app's router to understand what attribute to get from: `this.props.match.params.THEREMUSTBEFIELDNAME`

Comment: Hi @num8er, I have uploaded the project to GitHub, can you please have a look at it?
I need help in getting the posts from the employer.

Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/ravigohel/jobspection/

Comment: @RaviGohel better add it to Your question. I don't have time for code reviews.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the following code to get the value:

```
const userId = req.params.user;
```

Normally, MongoDB stores a document's id into "_id". I just want you to make sure that the user's id is stored in "user".

Sample Common code should be:

```
const userId = req.params.user;
Post.find({ _id: userId })
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(posts => {
              res.status(200).json(posts);
          })
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(404).json({ nopostfound: "No post found with that ID" })
    );
```

I also suggest to save the value in a constant variable and use the variable. It makes your code more readable.